# implement bluetooth connection for all smartphone users in react-native

Tags: bluetooth, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to scan and connect devices using Bluetooth in React-Native. I tried react-native-ble-manager and react-native-ble-plx plugins.

But I have a problem these plugins connected to special devices that have peripheral mode enabled. Look this answer.

Question:

How can I implement Bluetooth for all (at least all smartphones) devices in REACT-NATIVE?